# Capture Specific String of Text and Remove a String of Text from XML

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to to figure out how to display just the the word between the | and | in the description from the XML below. For example, the word "web" or "VideoGames".

I've tried this, but because each word has a different length, I'm unsuccessful. Also, i can't get rid of the |

```
<cfoutput>#Right(thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[x].metadata.xmlAttributes.v, 10)#</cfoutput>
```

I am also trying to do an opposite task - filter out the word between the | and | so it does not display. In otherwords taking the first item as an example, display the whole description, minus the word "web" or "VideoGames"

I've tried this, but again, I have the same problem as trying to filter out just the description, sans the word in between | and |.

```
<cfoutput>#left(thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[x].metadata.xmlAttributes.v, 500)#</cfoutput>
```

So my questions are...

1: How can i extract the word between | and | from the description element.

2: In a separate instance from number 1, how can I delete the word between | and  | in the description?

By the way "thefeed2" is what I am calling the XML feed .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<rsschannel>
<resultsnumbertotal>11    </resultsnumbertotal>
<eachresult>
<resultnumber N="1">
<U>/file.cfm?id=yahoocom    </U>
<T>Yahoo    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know |Web|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="2">
<U>/file.cfm?id=halo    </U>
<T>Halo    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Halo is a multi-billion dollar science fiction video game franchise created by Bungie and now managed by 343 Industries and owned by Microsoft Studios. |VideoGames|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="3">
<U>/file.cfm?id=bingcom    </U>
<T>Bing    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Bing is a search engine that brings together the best of search and people in your social networks to help you spend less time searching and more time doing. |Web|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="4">
<U>/file.cfm?id=lal    </U>
<T>Lakers    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="The Los Angeles Lakers are an American professional basketball team based in Los Angeles, California. They play in the Pacific Division |Sports|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="5">
<U>/file.cfm?id=quick    </U>
<T>Stay in the Know    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know |Misc|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="6">
<U>/file.cfm?id=multi    </U>
<T>Billion Dollars    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Halo is a multi-billion dollar science fiction video game franchise created by Bungie and now managed by 343 Industries and owned by Microsoft Studios. |Misc|"  />
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="7">
<U>/file.cfm?id=searching    </U>
<T>Searches    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Bing is a search engine that brings together the best of search and people in your social networks to help you spend less time searching and more time doing. |Web|" />
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="8">
<U>/file.cfm?id=LosAngeles    </U>
<T>Los Angeles    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="The Los Angeles Lakers are an American professional basketball team based in Los Angeles, California. They play in the Pacific Division |Sports|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="9">
<U>/file.cfm?id=quick    </U>
<T>Stay in the Know    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know |Misc|"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="10">
<U>/file.cfm?id=LosAngeles    </U>
<T>Los Angeles    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="The Los Angeles Lakers are an American professional basketball team based in Los Angeles, California. They play in the Pacific Division"/>
</resultnumber>

<resultnumber N="11">
<U>/file.cfm?id=quick    </U>
<T>Stay in the Know    </T>
<metadata N="description" V="Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know |SummaryofDescription|"/>
</resultnumber>

</eachresult>
</rsschannel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. For string manipulation, always takes a step back to look for patterns to help you get creative. For instance, CFMLs concept of "lists" makes for some fun times. More advanced users will always head straight to regular expressions, but this is definitely an advanced topic if you are just starting out. Instantly, I recognized your string as being a list separated by pipes (|). You can also see that sentences are a list of words separated by spaces. Here is some code.

```
 //set your string to something
 <cfset myString = "thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[x].metadata.xmlAttributes.v" />
//now let's treat the phrase as a list, we'll get position 2 of the list.
<cfset myWord = listGetAt(myString,2,'|');
//assuming you don't want the pipes in the clean string, let's just do a fast replace once
<cfset cleanString = replace(myString,"|#myWord#|","") />
//if you do want the pipes then you'll need a regex (a more advanced topic)
<cfset cleanStringWithPipes = rereplace(myString,"(\|)[ A-Za-z0-9]+(\|)","\1\2") />
```

Comment: Sweetness, thank you, this worked perfectly!!! My word gave the word in the | and | and cleanString gave a well, clean string without the word!

Comment: Do not do `rereplace(myString,"(\|)[ A-Za-z0-9]+(\|)","\1\2")` - that's silly. Simply do `rereplace(myString,"\|[ A-Za-z0-9]+\|","||")` if you're doing it that way.

Comment: Silly or awesome? I should have taken my own advice to step back.

Answer (score 1):

Will there always only be two `|` symbols? If so you can use `GetToken` to find the value

```
<cfset Mystring = GetToken(variable,1,'|') />
```

`GetToken` treats your variable like a list with a delimiter of `|`

To delete the word you can use `replace(variable,Mystring,'')`

Comment: Cool, I've never heard of GetToken before, very interesting! I tried the following, but it deleted the word "web" rather then the rest of the description. What did I do wrong?

#GetToken(thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[1].metadata.xmlAttributes.v,1,'|')#

Comment: I refer you to the sandbox master: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/784-ColdFusion-ListGetAt-vs-GetToken-.htm

Answer (score 1):

You want to use regex with REreplace(). Examples (in cfscript):

1)

```
origString = thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[x].metadata.xmlAttributes.v;
newString = REreplace(origString, "\|.*\|", "new text");
```

2)

```
origString = thefeed2.rsschannel.eachresult.resultnumber[x].metadata.xmlAttributes.v;
newString = REreplace(origString, "\|.*\|", "");
```

The regex `\|.*\|` will match any text that starts and ends with |.

Comment: Thank you, the second code worked beautifully! I believe the first is exactly the same, just a replace of text. 

I probably explained it badly, but for number 1, I want to extract and display the word, not replace it. For example, I want to show the word "web" or "VideoGames" and delete the rest of the text in the description

Comment: [rematch](http://cfdocs.org/rematch) can be used to extract the matched text. Also, `\|[^|]+\|` probably makes more sense than `\|.*\|` for this.